# Where is `use` defined in the perl source code?

Tags: perl, internals

Does anyone know where exactly in the source and the compilation stages `use` is defined in? I didn't see it looking for `CORE::GLOBAL::use` and I'm unsure of how to dive in looking for it. It's a pretty vague term.

Comment: `use` is not a function/operator that has any runtime effect. Instead, it is an implicit BEGIN block that does a `require`, and possibly performs imports or version checks. So it is probably “defined” pretty close to the parsing code.

Comment: If you are still on your quest to unload stuff I think you need to look into require. Have you asked for your requirements in the p5p mailing list yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `use` syntax is defined in the parser (`perly.y`). Excerpt:

```c
|   USE startsub
        { CvSPECIAL_on(PL_compcv); /* It's a BEGIN {} */ }
    BAREWORD BAREWORD optlistexpr ';'
        {
          SvREFCNT_inc_simple_void(PL_compcv);
          utilize($1, $2, $4, $5, $6);
          parser->parsed_sub = 1;
          $$ = NULL;
        }
```

Not knowing yacc, I have no idea what that's doing.

The `utilize()` function is `Perl_utilize()` from `op.c`. This code creates a BEGIN block that contains a `require`. The `veop` and `imop` variables may hold opcodes for checking the version or importing the requested elements:

```c
/* Fake up the BEGIN {}, which does its thing immediately. */
newATTRSUB(floor,
    newSVOP(OP_CONST, 0, newSVpvs_share("BEGIN")),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    op_append_elem(OP_LINESEQ,
        op_append_elem(OP_LINESEQ,
            newSTATEOP(0, NULL, newUNOP(OP_REQUIRE, 0, idop)),
            newSTATEOP(0, NULL, veop)),
        newSTATEOP(0, NULL, imop) ));
```

Links into the v5.26.0 source on the Github mirror:

- [`Perl_utilize()` in op.c](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.26.0/op.c#L6268)
- [USE statement in perly.y](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.26.0/perly.y#L349)

Answer (score -1):

It's in `CORE`.

`perl -w -E 'CORE::use Data::Dumper; print Dumper("a")'`

Comment: I'm not sure why that behavior is there, but I think @amon is right in the comments above. I just want to see the code to see what it's doing in C. I think what you're observing is just an illusion so people can think the process is sane and simple.

Comment: That was a good guess, but the `CORE::` pseudo-namespace is handled very early in the parser. Barewords starting with `CORE::` are equivalent to the normal keywords. So `CORE::use` is not a subroutine (e.g. you can't take a reference to it), but behaves exactly the same as the normal `use` keyword. Because this works through the parser and not through package name lookup, you could even `say 42 CORE::if $x`!

Comment: @amon there be dragons here.